# iPhone calendar events won't sync with Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, iphone

iPhone4 / Office 2010 x64 / Windows 7 Pro x64

Events entered in the iPhone calendar that have a specific start and end time do not sync with Outlook. Only events that are marked as "All-day" sync. Does anyone know a workaround / solution?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your iPhone settings, not Outlook. On the phone check Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendar.

Comment: Under Calendars, there are 2 configurable options - "New Invitation Alerts" and "Time Zone Support". Changing those accomplishes nothing with respect to the above issue.